# Generating doc for external files using Doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have my own sources and includes in these two folders:

```
/A/B/C/MyProject/src/

/A/B/C/MyProject/include/
```

But I also use a library xx that has headers in

```
/A/xx/include
```

In the configuration of doxygen I give the root folder of my project. So it only generates documentation for my source files and my header files. I would like to get also the documentation for the headers of xx.

Is this possible with doxygen?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to add the other path to the INPUT line in your doxyfile. The argument to INPUT is a space-separated list.

This may or may not result in what you want because that rather depends on what level of doxygen commentary has been implemented in those library headers.